# Must unitary matrices satisfying this property commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, inner-products

If A and B are unitary matrices such that A, B, and AB are all conjugate to diag(1,1,-1,-1), must AB=BA?  Why or why not?

Comment: by "conjugate" do you mean "similar"?

Comment: Yes. Conjugate or similar, either one.

Answer (score 3):

This is true, and it has nothing to do with unitarity. Let $g\in \operatorname{GL}_4(\mathbb{C})$ be such that $gAg^{-1}=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,-1,-1)$ so that
$$
gA^2g^{-1}=(gAg^{-1})^2=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,-1,-1)^2=1
$$
so $A^2=g^{-1}1g=1$. Likewise, $B^2=1$ and $ABAB=(AB)^2=1$. Therefore
\begin{align} 
AB-BA &=(AB-BA)ABAB\\
&=(ABAB-BAAB)AB\\
&=(1-1)AB\\
&=0.
\end{align}

Comment: Superb, many thanks!  Here n = 4 of course...

Comment: Yes thanks, I will edit.

Comment: +1. The proof can be slightly simplified: from $A^2=B^2=(AB)^2=I$, we get $ABAB=AA$ and hence $AB=(AB)^{-1}AA=B^{-1}A^{-1}AA=B^{-1}A=BA$.

Comment: Or even: $A$, $B$, and $AB$ are all self-inverse, so $AB = (AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1} = BA$.

Comment: @Chiaroscuro it can't get better than that... I would say that that's definitely the intended solution (if, as I'm assuming, it was given as a short exercise).